# Как программно можно найти и скачать иконку сайта?

Tags: vb.net

Как программно можно найти и скачать иконку сайта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

скачать файл favicon.ico  с корня?
или скачать html, распарсить и поискать там

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/upfiles/favicon.ico" />
```

где можно взять путь к инконке.